# Gitlab-CI: Dockerized Spring Boot with gradle failed on docker build

Tags: spring, spring-boot, docker, gitlab-ci

I'm trying to get into gitlab-ci, unfortunately the stage docker build fails. Here is the link to my repo: 
https://gitlab.com/systemxy/actuator-sample/-/jobs/131454962

Answer (score 0):

You have your repository set as private, please paste logs or make it public so we can have a look at this.

Comment: Thank you for feedback!
The mistake was that I used the Shared Runners. The case is solved by the definition of the specific runner